# Jekyll include image files next to markdown post file

Tags: jekyll

I started working with Jekyll a couple of days to import a Hugo blog.

There is this simple thing that I can't figure out.

It's my understanding that all folders starting with `_` will not be processed. It doesn't matter where the folder is it will not be processed except the `_posts` and `_pages`.

Let's assume I've got the following structure:

```
- _posts
  - folder1
    - 2017-02-05-Post1.md
    - 2017-02-05-Post1.png
```

Then my output is:

```
- _site
  - 2016
    - 02
      - 05
        - Post1.html
```

I can't figure out how to make Jekyll do something with the image.
I've tried all of the following the `_config.yaml`.

```
include:
- .htaccess
- "_posts/**/*.gif"
- "/_posts/**/*.gif"
- "/_posts/*.png"
- "_posts/**/*.gif"
- "_posts/*.png"
- "**/*.gif"
- "**/*.png"
#  - "_posts\**\*.gif"
#  - "_posts\*.png"
```

I can't understand Jekyll.